# $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable with properties $f'(x)=3xf(x),\;f(x)>0,\;\forall x,\;f(0)=10$. Find value o f$f^{(4)}(0)+f^{(2k+1)},\;k=10$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question**

$f(x)$ is an infinitely differentiable function with the following properties

- $f'(x)=3xf(x)$
- $f(x)>0, \;\;\forall x $
- $f(0)=10$

Calculate the value of the expression $f^{(4)}(0)+f^{(2k+1)}, \;\;k=10$

**Answer**

> $270$

Comment: Hello: can you provide your attempt? If you're stuck for where to start, think about what you would do for the second derivative

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating?

Comment: $f^{(2k+1)}$ is a function, what is meant is probably also the function value at $x=0$?